# Increase quantity values in $_SESSION when adding same product

Tags: php, session

I want to add more quantity by clicking add to cart with the same product, But my code it's working with max quantity by 2.

**My code:**

**cart_process.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["product_code"]))
{
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $new_product[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //create a new product array 
    }

    //we need to get product name and price from database.
    $statement = $mysqli_conn->prepare("SELECT product_name, product_price FROM products_list WHERE product_code=? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $new_product['product_code']);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($product_name, $product_price);


    while($statement->fetch()){ 
        $new_product["product_name"] = $product_name; //fetch product name from database
        $new_product["product_price"] = $product_price;  //fetch product price from database
        $new_product["product_qty"] = 1;

        if(isset($_SESSION["products"])){  //if session var already exist
            if(isset($_SESSION["products"][$new_product['product_code']])) //check if item already exist in products array add more quantity +1
            {
                $_SESSION["products"][$new_product['product_code']] = $new_product["product_qty"]++;
            }           
        }

        $_SESSION["products"][$new_product['product_code']] = $new_product; //update products with new item array       //update products with new item array   

    }

    $total_items = count($_SESSION["products"]); //count total items
    die(json_encode(array('items'=>$total_items))); //output json 

}
```

Output on my first click add to cart:

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [TSH1] => Array
                (
                    [product_color] => Red
                    [product_size] => M
                    [product_code] => TSH1
                    [product_name] => Cool T-shirt
                    [product_price] => 8.50
                    [product_qty] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

And output on second click add the same product to cart again:

```
[product_qty] => 2 // Quantity has been added when I click add the same product to cart
```

But when I click add the same product to cart again it won't add more quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Unset the [product_qty] and increase the counter  ... add back to session array

Comment: `unset($_SESSION["products"][$new_product['product_qty']])` right?